# Why scp is not working when remote server is using zsh?

Tags: ssh, server, zsh, scp

I compiled and installed zsh on server, and put the following line into `.bashrc`:

```
[ -f $ZSH/bin/zsh ] && exec $ZSH/bin/zsh -l
```

And zsh works well.

Then when I'm using scp from my local computer to copy some files to the server, like

```
$ scp test.txt user@server:~/
```

it would stuck forever, without any outputs.

And if I comment the shell line above in `.bashrc`, scp worked again.

Comment: I have the same problem. Yet I do not have root access to add zsh to /etc/shells. I guess the only way is to start zsh manually.

Answer (score 3):

Put `[ -f $ZSH/bin/zsh ] && exec $ZSH/bin/zsh -l` in your `.bash_profile` not `.bashrc`.

`.bash_profile` is only sourced for interactive shells, `.bashrc` is sourced all the time. Even when you're just trying to execute a single command on the remote, e.g. `scp` instead of an interactive shell (`ssh`) and this leads to complications.

Comment: Thanks, I've encountered this problem too. According to your answer, the problem was solved perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you've done this already but

> if you DO have root access, make sure zsh goes in /etc/shells on all appropriate machines, including NIS clients, or you may have problems with FTP to that machine

From [zsh-FAQ](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/FAQ/zshfaq01.html)